# Jackson Cannot handle managed/back reference error with @ManyToOne hibernate relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jackson

I make shoe shop application with Spring Boot + Hibernate + PostgreSQL and I have table with Goods and Manufacturers. One manufacturer can have many goods

I have made all relations with entities in my project, and faced with some problems while testing my Controller. I need to send post request body via Postman

[image]
And get 415 error.
`Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.velov.shoeshop.entities.Good]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot handle managed/back reference 'defaultReference': back reference type (`java.util.List<com.velov.shoeshop.entities.Good>`) not compatible with managed type (com.velov.shoeshop.entities.Good)`

I get errors with POST and PUT methods

And there is my code:

class for Good:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "goods")
public class Good {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    private String title;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "sex")
    private sexType sexType;

    /**
     * proved and it actually works!
     */
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "ManufacturerId")
    Manufacturer manufacturer; //Many goods can refer to one manufacturer


    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "good")//Uni-directional reference to size array
    List<Size> sizes;
```

Class for Manufacturer:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "manufacturers")
public class Manufacturer {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int Id;

    @Column(name = "ManufacturerName")
    private String manufacturerName;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "Telephone")
    private String telephone;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE},
            mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    private List<Good> goods;
```

My REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyRESTController {

    @Autowired
    private GoodService goodService;

    @GetMapping("/goods")
    public List<Good> showAllGoods() {
        List<Good> allGoods = goodService.getAllGoods();
        return allGoods;
    }

    @PostMapping("/goods")
    public Good addNewGood(@RequestBody Good good) {
        goodService.saveGood(good);
        return good;
    }

    @PutMapping("/goods")
    public Good updateGood(@RequestBody Good good) {
        goodService.saveGood(good);
        return good;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/goods/{id}")
    public String deleteGood(@PathVariable int id) {
        goodService.deleteGood(id);
        return "Good with id = " + id + "deleted";
    }
}
```

JSON Examle I need to send as body:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Dean",
    "sexType": "MAN",
    "manufacturer": {
      "id": 1,
      "manufacturerName": "Ralf",
      "address": "Moscow",
      "telephone": "9-999-999-99-99"
    },
    "sizes": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "size": 42,
        "quantity": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "size": 45,
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ],
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

Postman error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-07T15:02:08.771+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "path": "/api/goods"
}
```

I tried to write @JsonIdentityInfo and change JSON body

Answer (score 0):

you can use the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation on the goods field of the Manufacturer entity to ignore the Good entity during serialization and deserialization. You can also remove the @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference annotations as they are not necessary with the @JsonIgnoreProperties annotation.

Comment: If I remove those annotations, threre will be problem with infinite loop, `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` are solutions of this prob